# Google Calendar API, EventList with MaxResult, is not available in Microsoft Flow

Tags: google-api, power-automate

I am trying to let my virtual agent to return the searching result of a specific event with its deadline.

But virtual agent couldn't respond under branch:
[image: But virtual agent couldn't respond under branch]

and I don't want to return a list of events but one specific event since I am going to limited the user input with pre-defined options and there should match exactly.

I looked into the Google AP Documentation:

[image: Google API documentation]

and seems like I could simply limited the MaxResult to 1 and it should be okay. As you can see, in picture 1, Flow doesn't have that parameter for me, and I could find nowhere I can type anycode to modify that.

Answer (score 0):

I finished that project. The way I edit it is also through the agent. I break my flow to a simple flow that will do "search" by looking up the event name instead of time and other details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).